# Jmeter Request Execution

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to understand jmeter's core behavior.
Say I am executing a HTTP request (single user and single sampler but different variable values) in infinite loop.
In the above case does jmeter send a request and waits for the response before sending the next request OR it sends the requests without waiting for response?

Answer (score 9):

Jmeter uses a thread-based model where each thread will wait for a response before sending another request. In other words it will only drive the load as fast as application can take it.
In JMeter you specify a number of threads in a ThreadGroup which equate to virtual users, and the threads attempt to execute the script as many times as possible.

---

If you want to maintain a constant rate, you can use multiple threads and use a [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) to set the request rate: if there are enough threads, it should be possible to maintain the rate even though some threads are waiting for a response. Here belongs also custom [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer) which is more flexible.

Another possibility seems to be to use e.g. either [Ultimate Thread Group](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup) or [Stepping Thread Group](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup) from [jmeter plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/).

In this context you can also look onto the `Response Timeout` field available for any jmeter's sampler - number of milliseconds to wait for a response.

Comment: Well, suppose you can upvote or accept [if it was useful](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: I wonder why JMeter indeed "will only drive the load as fast as application can take it". If I am a user of a service (and JMeter should emulate the user), I do not care if the service can take my requests or not, I just keep sending them.